# placing identical html in multiple places

Tags: javascript, html, embed, swipe

I am building a webapp, which, in mobile browsers, will consist of two views (A and B) which the user can swipe between. On larger screens, the two views will be placed side by side.

I am using iosSlider to create the swipe-effect.

What I would like to do is use some command that will output A and B, for instance two functions that just output a very long string, such that I can write something like

```
if mobile:
    <slider-construction>
        <slide1> funk_A() </slide1>
        <slide2> funk_B() </slide2>
    </slider-construction>  
else:
    <div>funk_A()</div>
    <div>funk_B()</div>
```

Am I doing things the sensible way? I realize that another way would be to use some swipe-script that allowed me to disable it such that the slides were simply placed side by side (it doesn't seem like iosSlider has that feature?). I have tried simply placing A and B in separate .html-files and using the embed-command to place them inside the slides, but that seems to disable the swipe effect. Using document.write(), or anything similar to that (such as innerHTML of the slides) is also rather impractical, because those functions only assume one line of code at the time.

thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found 3 different solutions to this:

### HTML-solution:

#### The "include" command

Use

```
<!--#include virtual="/directory/included.html" -->
```

and change the ending of the parent file to **.shtml**.

### iosSLider-solutions:

#### slide-width

If the total widths of the slides is smaller than the width of the slider, then they will automatically be placed next to each other. This is demonstrated in the very last example in the benchmarks which ship with iosSlider.

#### destroy-method

It is also possible simply to disable the slider, using the invocation

```
$(".iosSlider").iosSlider("destroy");
```

Note that ".iosSlider" here is the same definition as what was used to initiate the iosSlider, aka the call:

```
$('.iosSlider').iosSlider({
                (options)
            });
```

In this case, the slides will be treated as divs, (though still with the formatting, such as  width and height, as was applied when the slider was active).